# Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException

Tags: spring-mvc

I a trying to send object from client to server. Below is the Controller using spring mvc.

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

public class User{
        public String name;
        public String email;



        public User() {
            super();
        }
        public User(String name, String email) {
            super();
            this.name = name;
            this.email = email;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }



    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/getUsers", method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody User getUser(User user){
        return user;
    }}
```

In client side I am sending object in post like this
http://localhost:2015/spring/getUsers

```
POST /spring/getUsers HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:2015
Cache-Control: no-cache

{"name":"vinod", "email":"vinod@gmaol.com" }
```

But I am getting error at server side like this

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.vinod.spring.HomeController$User]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.vinod.spring.HomeController$User.<init>()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try make the refactoring for your User class to another file, and put a reference of it in your controller using the @Resource annotation. Maybe the exception was throwed because User class is nested.

Example:
User.java

```
@Component
public class User{
    public String name;
    public String email;



    public User() {
        super();
    }
    public User(String name, String email) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }



}
```

HomeController.java

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Resource
    User user;

    @RequestMapping(value="/getUsers", method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody User getUser(User user){
        return user;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please give example. How to use @Resource annotation?

Comment: But user.getName() and user.getEmail() is null. User class is not initializing. Why? Even though I am sending user object at client side as POST /spring/getUsers HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:2015
Cache-Control: no-cache

{"name":"vinod", "email":"vinod@gmaol.com" }